# Python to merge 2 dictionaries in a list and persevere duplicate keys

Tags: python

My requirement is to merge the below two dictionaries in to single dictionaries and also preserve the duplicate keys

```
a = [ { 'enabled': True, 'health': '/favicon.ico', 'test': 'id'},
      { 'enabled': True, 'disableAccess': False, 'appliance': 'test.com',      'SSOEnabled': False}]
```

Desired output:

```
a = [ { 'enabled: True, 'health;: '/favicon.ico', 'test': 'id', 'enabled': True,  'disableAccess': False,  'appliance' : 'test.com', 'SSOEnabled': False}]
```

Can someone please help this requirement.

Comment: Not happening, sorry. Dictionaries don't support duplicate keys.

Comment: You can't. `dicts` can't have duplicate keys.